# Have people tried to find the area under a curve by means other than integration?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

It seems pretty frustrating that some definite integrals can only be evaluated numerically, so have people tried to find another method of finding the area under a curve that isn't numerical? I'm talking about a method that gives a function that can be evaluated in order to find the area. Is there only one such function for a given curve (the function given by integrating)? Thanks.

Comment: Except in calculus homework assignments, I'd say that the vast majority of functions don't have anti-derivatives. In fact, I think it's surprising that some functions *do* have antiderivatives. The fact that an area can sometimes be calculated from a simple formula seems quite remarkable, to me.

Comment: A significant, related question is what's your *definition* of area? Intuitively, the area of a region is the amount of 2-dimensional space that it occupies, but that isn't a precise, mathematical definition. Part of the reason why integral calculus is so useful when computing area is that integrals *define* area; we use integrals to make our intuitive definition of area precise. So even though it can be very difficult/impossible to compute the exact value of $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ for most $f(x)$, at least it allows us to talk about area in a meaningful way for complicated curves.

Comment: @bubba: In a technical sense, the majority of functions don't have antiderivatives. But any function a person is likely to encounter on the street will be integrable. My understanding is that even most computer scientists, physicists, and economists (who I think we can agree are "closer to the metal" than most other disciplines) do not have to deal with non-integrable functions very often. [That could be flatly wrong, though; I admit ignorance of common practice in these fields].

Comment: @Eric -- the OP talked about "a function that can be evaluated in order to find the area". I interpreted that as a closed-form anti-derivative. I agree that most functions in applications fields are integrable (probably), but I didn't think that was the question. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @bubba: *Some* functions have to have anti-derivatives, because otherwise no function would be differentiable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what we mean by "integrating."

There were many *quadratures,* both ancient and early modern, that did not involve the calculation of antiderivatives in the first-year calculus sense. By the middle of the seventeenth century, all curves of the shape $y=x^\alpha$ had in principle been dealt with, along with a number of others, such as the cycloid. One might mention in this context the Method of Fermat, and the *indivisibles* of Torricelli and Cavalieri. This was all quite a number of years before the official appearance of the calculus at the hands of Newton and Leibniz.

Comment: Is it possible to have another function that replaces the antiderivative and that can be found for many general functions? (unlike the example you mentioned where a formula would be used only for specific functions of the form $x^a$)

Comment: The problem is assigning meaning to the question. If for a continuous function $f(x)$ we want a function $G(x)$  so that the area under the curve $y=f(x)$, above the $x$-axis, from $a$ to $b$ is always $G(b)-G(a)$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we will have $G'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: But if you could find the area between $(a, b)$ by calculating for example $G(b^2)-G(b^3)$ for any $a, b$ would the function G necessarily be a transformation of the antiderivative or could it be a totally different function?

Comment: That would make it such a close relative that, under my (not formulated precisely) assignment of meaning, it would be effectively the same thing. One can use fancier disguises, such as going to polar coordinates, where we are no longer approximating using rectangles, but instead using sectors of circles. That might make a better fit with what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok thanks (5 char left)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure that this argument holds, so please comment on it.

Let's say you have a curve for which there is no exact formula for the anti-derivative. Let's say you just found a magic way to come up with an exact formula that calculates the area anyway (the formula must have as parameters the end points of the independent variable, or you cheat yourself from your own constraint of the method being general).

The fundamental theorem of calculus is a statement about integrals and derivatives; it doesn't care whether there is a nice formula for it or not. If your formula calculates the area, it *must* be equal to the anti-derivative evaluated at the second point of the domain, minus the anti-derivative at the first point.

I venture - then - that you can use your magic formula for the area to come up with an exact formula for the anti-derivative. At worst, the formula will be an implicit equation, but it will be there.

Therefore, either you were wrong about there not being a non-numerical formula for the anti-derivative, or there is no such method to find a formula for the area when there is no exact formula for the anti-derivative.

I'm not saying that there are no 'non-calculus' ways to come up with a formula for some curves; they exist for (a subset of) the cases where a formula for the anti-derivative exists. I'm saying you can't use those methods to get around the cases where there is no exact formula for the anti-derivative.

Comment: That's a good idea but if you had a way to find the area and you wanted to find an exact function that goes trough the necessary points, you would need to fit the function trough an infinite number of points, but that might be possible (I guess) depending on the method you use to find the area.

Comment: This is nicely-stated! One additional comment related to the original question is that _special values_ of areas (e.g., the area under a Gaussian over the real line) may be possible to express in elementary terms even if an elementary antiderivative does not exist.

Comment: @Ovi: Euro Micelli's argument shows that any putative general area formula (with "general" interpreted along the lines in your question) _is_ an antiderivative; no curve fitting is required.

Answer (score 2):

[Monte Carlo integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) methods can be adapted to be "non-numerical." The idea boils down to randomly sampling a curve bounded by a much simpler one (e.g., a rectangle) at many discrete points. One then counts how many samples were inside the curve and how many were outside. Knowing the area of the simpler bounding shape, the area of (or under) the curve can be estimated.

The classic example of this is throwing darts (but it could be dropping pins or marbles) at a circle inscribed within a square. Often simple scheme is used to estimate $\pi$ (very inefficiently), but it of course also estimates the area of the circle:

[image]

Monte Carlo techniques, in their numerical forms, are important for things such as [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) to obtain random numbers from a desired distribution.

Comment: +thanks, not exactly what I was looking for but very cool idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are some curves that form figures that have known geometric properties. Here are some examples:

$$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

[image]

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\pi{r}^2=\frac{1}{2}\pi$$

---

$$y=x$$

[image]

From the equation for the area of a right triangle $A=\frac{1}{2}ba$, the area under the curve from $0$ to $x=b$:

$$A=\frac{1}{2}b^2$$

---

There are many more of such figures (some curves form trapezoids, rectangles, ellipses, etc), which have methods of calculating their area that long predate the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I meant general ways that could be applied to a large number of functions, such as finding the antiderivative.

Comment: @Ovi Do you want me to generalize this process? This could be generalized, for example, for the case of $y=mx+b$ without using integration, and that would be an infinite number of functions.

Comment: Yea but this method is restricted for $y=mx+b$ , and the method above is restricted to circles. But I was wondering if there is a way to find a formula for an extensive set of functions, like the antiderivative does. The examples which you showed are much more restricted than the antiderivative

Answer (score 1):

The one-word answer to your question is "yes".  If you chase all the links previous to 1665 in this Wikipedia article, you'll have yourself a good history of the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_calculus_and_mathematical_analysis